# Circuit to truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

Here are $2$ circuits, the goal is to convert them to truth tables.

[image: 2 circuits]

I'm thinking about converting them to expressions first, then making the tables.

So the first one should be $(1)$, and the second one $(2)$.

$$(xy)+(x'x') = (xy)+x'\tag{1}$$
$$(xyz)+(xx'z')+(x'yz')+(x'x'z) = xyz + x'yz' + x'z\tag{2}$$

Am I right so far?

Comment: You are right with respect to your results. But the solution can be made easier than writing expressions to each of the wires. Oberserve that the output stage is an `OR` gate, the intermediate stage consists of `AND` gates, and the input stage includes non-inverted and inverted inputs. Therefore, you can directly translate the circuits to sum-of-product minterms, i.e. the truthtable rows which have a `1` as output value.

Comment: For me are the expressions fine.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Your expressions for the first $(1)$ and second $(2)$ circuit are correct.

$$xy+x'\tag{1}$$

$$xyz + x'yz' + x'z\tag{2}$$

Both expressions $(1,2)$ can be simplified further with a truth table or [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), followed by the [distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) $(3,4)$.

---

The $1^{st}$ expression:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&x'&x\\\hline 
y'&\color{blue}{1}&0\\
y&\color{blue}{1},\color{red}{1}&\color{red}{1}
\end{array}

$$\color{blue}{x'}+\color{red}{y}\tag{3}$$

---

The $2^{nd}$ expression:

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&x'y'&x'y&xy&xy'\\ \hline
z'&0&\color{blue}{1}&0&0\\
z&\color{red}{1}&\color{red}{1},\color{blue}{1},\color{orange}{1}&\color{orange}{1}&0
\end{array}

$$\color{blue}{x'y}+\color{red}{x'z}+\color{orange}{yz}\tag{4}=x'(y+z)+yz$$